# Magento2: How to keep website online/in the air when working on Magento like command line

Tags: magento2, error, http-error-500

When you do things like deploy compile website, having it in developer mode things like that

You get your website for example in:

> http error 500.

How to keep everything working, online in the air, so the visitors always see your website online?

Comment: My suggestion to deploying on website downtime. My point of view, when you deploying website, please enable maintain mode at magento2

Comment: Yes that makes sense, maintenance mode, and then create own maintenance mode ? Because when you deploy or something and your website is during that offline, its not good for visitor exactly at that moment

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
If you are on production

Step 1: Copy Sourcecode to another place, run commline....

Step 2: If OK, point to this source or replace old source

Gud luck